# Vectors In Space - Solving 3 x 3 Linear Systems - Row Reduction

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations

Reduce the system of equations:

$$2x+y-z=3\\
mx-2y+z=1\\
x+2y+mz=-1$$

to a form in which the solutions may be determined for all real values of m.

So far, I have written out the equation in its augmented form. I'm not too sure how to type that out on here though :).
This question is confusing me because I'm not sure which it means that the solutions may be determined for all values of m.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html

Comment: not helpful at all

Comment: what do you mean with $$mx-2y+z=$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubener I changed it

Comment: add last two equations get $(x+z)(m+1)=0$

Comment: Are you user 466749 (corthy)?

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta=-m^2-6m-5$, $\Delta_x=-7m-7$, $\Delta_y=-3m^2+3m+6$ and $\Delta_z=7m+7$.

1. If $m\neq-1$ and $m\neq-5$ we obtain $\left(\frac{7}{m+5}, \frac{3(m-2)}{m+5},-\frac{7}{m+5}\right)$.
2. if $m=-5$ then the system has no solutions.
3. If $m=-1$ we obtain $2x+y=z+3$ and $x+2y=z-1$,

which give infinitely many solutions:
$$\left\{\left(\frac{z+7}{3},\frac{z-5}{3},z\right)|z\in\mathbb R\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

from your equation (1) we get:
$$x=-y/2+z/2+3/2$$
this equation we set in your equation (2) and (3):
$$m \left( -y/2+z/2+3/2 \right) -2\,y+z-1=0$$ ($\star$)
$$mz+3/2\,y+z/2+5/2=0$$
solving the last equation for $y$ we get:
$$y=-2/3\,mz-z/3-5/3$$
this equation we setting in ($\star$) and factorizing we have:
$$1/3\, \left( m+1 \right)  \left( mz+5\,z+7 \right) =0$$
and if $$m=-1$$ then the equation is fulfilled for all real $z$.